# Parse Enum with FlagsAttribute to a SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, enums

I've got an Enum with Flags attribute.

```
  [Flags]
    public enum AlcoholStatus
    {
        NotRecorded = 1,
        Drinker = 2,
        NonDrinker = 4
    }
```

I am creating a Sqlparameter as below.

```
new SqlParameter("@AlcoholStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = (int) AlcoholStatus}
```

If AlcoholStatus has all the values (NotRecorded | Drinker | NonDrinker) it returns 7 as the value for the SqlParameter.

I am parsing this parameter for a stored procedure and I prefer if I can parse the value as "1,2,3,". What's the best way of doing this?

Or is there any other easy way to filter records by parsing integer value 7 to the stored procedure?

EDIT : This happens in a filter functionally where user wants to see people with any of above statuses.
It's a quite complicated sql query. There I filter AlcoholStatus as below

```
WHERE AlcoholStatus IN "1,2,4,"
```

Comment: but this would never happen, right (NotRecorded | Drinker | NonDrinker) they are mutually exclusive, so why don't you just rewrite your enum to have integer values of 1,2 and 3 respectively?

Comment: Maybe if you're in denial, or split-personality it could be 2+4? (I'm assuming the 2+3 is a typo by the OP)

Comment: @Brad : I am trying to do a filter. So, these are checkboxes and user an select all three or two of them. In that case this happend even though they are mutually exclusive normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote below method to get the comma separated enum ids in order to parse that to the database.

```
private static string GetAlcoholStatuses(Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus? alcoholStatus)
{
    if (alcoholStatus == null)
        return string.Empty;

    Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus alcoholStatusValue = alcoholStatus.Value;
    string alcoholStatuses = string.Empty;

    if (alcoholStatusValue.HasFlag(Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.Drinker))
    {
        alcoholStatuses = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", alcoholStatuses, (int)Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.Drinker, ",");
    }
    if (alcoholStatusValue.HasFlag(Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.NonDrinker))
    {
        alcoholStatuses = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", alcoholStatuses, (int)Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.NonDrinker, ",");
    }
    if (alcoholStatusValue.HasFlag(Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.NotRecorded))
    {
        alcoholStatuses = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", alcoholStatuses, (int)Enums.Enums.AlcoholStatus.NotRecorded, ",");
    }

    return alcoholStatuses;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Leaving the aside of whether that enum *makes sense* as a `[Flags]`, IMO the only sensible way of storing this data is in an `int` column. Just *store the value* - nothing else is required. Trying to coerce it as a `varchar` is a mistake. The job of the DB is to *store data*, not to care about presentation.

If you need to filter by this you can use bitwise operators in the search, but note that performance is impacted since when searching by combination (rather than via equality, which can use a non-clustered index). If you need to search *on arbitrary combinations*, then consider denormalization instead. If you only need to search *on predictable bits* then you can lift those out with a calculated persisted indexed column - i.e. you can have an automatic `IsDrinker` column (`bit`) that represents bit 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass 7 down to the stored procedure and kiss goodbye to any benefits you might get from an index on the AlcoholStatus column if you start AND'ing values in a WHERE clause.

Something like the below might be what you're after if you need to build up a string of IDs.  Optimize as necessary - I've not taken into account that there are only three flags in your enum, for example.

You'll also want to watch out for SQL injection if you're fiddling with strings in your SQL when building up statements.

```
string values = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
  if((((int)AlcoholStatus) & (1 << i)) != 0) {
    if(values != "") {
      values += ",";
    }

    values += (i + 1).ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Up front, I know very little about sequel-server... but...

Did you mean a proprty `new SqlParameter("@AlcoholStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar) {Value = (int) client.AlcoholStatus}` of the imaginary "Client" class (instead of the enum *type* AlcoholStatus)?

Also I would tend to think that a "Binary Flags" field would be "naturally" be stored in an integer field... and probably an unsigned one at that. VarChar just seems a strange choice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to filter for certain scenarios, e.g., you can use bitwise operations for your where, e.g., SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE AlcoholStatus & 0x3 would pick out Not Recorded and Drinker simultaneously.  You could also put together a stored procedure which converts AlcoholStatus to a string like 1,2,3 by using a series of CASE WHENs.